# How does MPI_Ssend work?

Tags: matrix, parallel-processing, mpi

I am currently working on MPI codes on FORTRAN 90 and have some doubts regarding the implementation of MPI_Ssend. I have a matrix A which has 8 columns. The 8 columns are divided into 4 processors 0,1,2 and 3. After distributing the columns by using MPI_Scatter, I need to send the column from one processor to the adjacent one. So I planned to use MPI_Ssend so as to make sure that the column is first received by the processor and then sent to the other adjacent processor. I don't know the problem, but can someone tell me if the implementation of the algorithm is correct?

> ```
>  if(id .eq. 0) then
>                 call MPI_Send(b1,dim2*col,MPI_Integer,1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
>                 call MPI_Recv(b1,dim2*col,MPI_Integer,num_procs-1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
>            else
>                call MPI_Recv(b1,dim2*col,MPI_Integer,flag3,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
>                call MPI_Ssend(b1,dim2*col,MPI_Integer,flag,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
>            endif
> ```

(id is the processor rank and just consider others as some variable. I want to understand if the point-to-point communication used will work or not ? I am first using simple MPI_Send for master processor because if I use MPI_Ssend for every processor none of them will send data before they receive.

Comment: You are receiving into a buffer and then sending its content to the next process. If the chain of receives and sends forms a closed loop, then it is nothing more than a broadcast of the data that rank 0 holds. Use [`MPI_BCAST`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.10/man3/MPI_Bcast.3.php) instead.

Comment: Hi, so I changed by algorithm a bit and now it uses simple MPI_Send and MPI_Recv to transfer column data from one processor to another.

call MPI_Send (b1,dim2*col,MPI_Integer,flag,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)

call MPI_Recv(b1,dim2*col,MPI_Integer,flag3,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)

I tried to use flag variables and found out that the error is between these two lines. Also the error is given by 'Error: forrtl: error (69): process interrupted (SIGINT)'. Do you have any idea what does this error mean ?

Comment: The program compiles but when I try to run the executable, it runs on 1 processor but on two processor it hangs and then when I kill the operation it gives the above error.

Comment: It would help if you would show how `flag` and `flag3` are computed. In MPI it is really important who talks with whom. Make sure that for any `MPI_Send` there is a matching `MPI_Recv` and vice versa. If you have access to the TotalView debugger (commercial, but often available at many HPC sites), you can use it to get a visual snapshot of the communication graph of the program and see if some ranks are sending/receiving messages to/from ranks that are not expecting them/willing to send.